# Why do I see this on "View XML Attibutes"?

Tags: android-studio

Look here, this is **what I see**: [My view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpNoN.png)
And what **I should see**: [What I should see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRJbl.png)

---

Do you know what's the **problem**? How can I **solve** it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the little icon with the two arrows at the top of your first screenshot? Press that. It'll take you back to the view with all of the attributes. What you're currently seeing is a list of the most important attributes.

Edit: failing that, press the settings icon and select `'All attributes table'`

Comment: Okay thanks, the solution I was searching for was "All attributes table"